# How do I compile code with globals in Typescript?

Tags: 9

Hi I'd like to use Typescript in my Drupal 9 Theme. I've setup compilation... but once I start declaring new behaviors like so:

```
(function ($: any, Drupal: any) {
  Drupal.behaviors.my_behavior = {
    attach: function (context: any, settings: any) {
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Ts compiler give me TS2304: Cannot find name 'jQuery'. and TS2304: Cannot find name 'Drupal'. while everything works fine in vanilla js.
Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

Seems variable from the global scope are not loaded with ts files, how can I circumvent this problem and make it works with drupal js framework ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252225/call-a-global-variable-inside-module

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. 
Don't know if we should close the question though: it could help other drupalers new to typescript like me

Comment: I’d tend to agree that this isn’t Drupal-specific enough for here (it’s the equivalent of a PHP variable not being defined). Your chosen solution isn’t ideal either, better to include the proper type definitions in your project, ie https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts

Comment: This is about TypeScript syntax—it is not Drupal-specific.

Comment: All true, but, when you try to declare your first ts behavior you hit this weird wall seemingly unrelated to types and get confused, wish justify a question in my book => because it helps.
but whatever it is closed anyway...

Comment: You should get rid of jQuery. jQuery was cool 20 years ago when there was still InTeRnOt ExPloUr 8. But nowadays you should get rid of that dependency and write Vanilla JS.

Comment: @Thony after a bit of thought i was probably too quick to vote to close this. The jquery part has a generic answer but `Drupal` might have some proper type definitions out there somewhere and if so it would be useful to have that documented somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to cilefen and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252225/call-a-global-variable-inside-module

this works:

```
declare var jQuery: any;
declare var Drupal: any;

(function ($: any, Drupal: any) {
  Drupal.behaviors.api_table_ieceecategories_graphic = {
    attach: function (context: any, settings: any) {},
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

DISC: I am using "any" type to prove compilation works, good typescript should use precise typing...